# knife solo fails to prepare Ubuntu ARM Server

Tags: chef-infra, knife-solo

Using Knife solo to provision an ARM server with Chef but it silently fails.

- Verify by checking for [chef-solo](https://docs.chef.io/chef_solo.html) a command that is required for provisioning a system with Chef.

#### x86 / Succeeding Process - Abridged

```
Bootstrapping Chef...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 20507  100 20507    0     0  17452      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 17452
ubuntu 16.04 x86_64
Getting information for chef stable 12.17.44 for ubuntu...
downloading https://omnitruck-direct.chef.io/stable/chef/metadata?v=12.17.44&p=ubuntu&pv=16.04&m=x86_64
  to file /tmp/install.sh.4824/metadata.txt
...
...
Preparing to unpack .../chef_12.17.44-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking chef (12.17.44-1) over (12.17.44-1) ...
Setting up chef (12.17.44-1) ...
Thank you for installing Chef!

ssh root@success
root@success:~# chef-solo -v
Chef: 12.17.44
```

#### Arm server / Failing Process

```
Bootstrapping Chef...
Updating apt caches...
Installing required packages...
Installing rubygems from source...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  243k  100  243k    0     0   981k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  999k

ssh root@failure
root@failure:~# chef-solo -v
-bash: chef-solo: command not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knife solo is failing to provision Arm servers. [The bug is being tracked for the 0.7.0 release](https://github.com/matschaffer/knife-solo/issues/490) but the [release doesn't look imminent](https://github.com/matschaffer/knife-solo/milestone/4)

[This part of the code handles the chipset](https://github.com/matschaffer/knife-solo/blob/master/lib/knife-solo/bootstraps/linux.rb#L82) Likely that Debian Arm platform fails in a similar manner (untested).